# Enabling Ruby PostGIS support on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, postgis

I'm trying to enable PostGIS in my Rails app on Heroku. My `Gemfile` includes the `activerecord-postgis-adapter` gem:

```
gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter', '3.0.0'
```

However, after booting up my instance, I don't see full support enabled:

```
$ heroku run irb
Running `irb` attached to terminal... up, run.5549
irb(main):001:0> require 'rgeo'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> RGeo::Geos.supported?
=> false
```

I've added the [heroku-geo-buildpack](https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack/),as specified in the [PostGIS article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgis), though I'm using the newer, true multi-buildpack format:

```
$ heroku buildpacks
=== staging Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git#1.3
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git#v140
```

I'm confused, since my build process looks correct:

```
-----> Multipack app detected
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> geos/gdal/proj app detected
       Using geos version: 3.4.2
       Using gdal version: 1.11.1
       Using proj version: 4.8.0_1
-----> Vendoring geo libraries done
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
...
```

What am I missing? I don't have a `BUILDPACK_URL` environmental variable set, as I gather it's for the old multi-buildpack approach.

Comment: Oh, this is embarrassing. It looks like I missed the fact that the Hobby tier databases don't support it. I guess that's my problem, then, though I would have expected to see some errors.

Comment: Yes, only production tier databases.   Which are:  

standard-0 premium-0,
standard-2 premium-2, 
standard-4 premium-4, 
standard-5 premium-5,
standard-6 premium-6,
standard-7 premium-7 enterprise-7, 
enterprise-8

Comment: You should definitely accept an answer to this. Had the same issue, and the solution was NOT obvious at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostGIS does work with Heroku Free dyno and :
- Rails 4.2
- activerecord-postgis-adapter 3.1.4

You have to:

1. set your config/database.yml like this:

---

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: adopt_your_geek_development
  username: postgres
  host: mydb.com
  port: 9999
  postgis_extension: postgis
  schema_search_path: public,postgis

...

production:
  <<: *default
  database: appname_production
  username: appname
  password: <%= ENV['ADOPT_YOUR_GEEK_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  postgis_extension: postgis
  schema_search_path: public,postgis
```

---

2. Add buildpacks:

---

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

With the following .buildpacks file:

```
$ cat .buildpacks 
https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

---

3. Then add a little monckey patch in config/environments/production.rb

---

```
module ActiveRecord
   module ConnectionHandling
     class MergeAndResolveDefaultUrlConfig
       private
       def config
         @raw_config.dup.tap do |cfg|
           if url = ENV['DATABASE_URL']
             cfg[@env] ||= {}
             cfg[@env]["url"] ||= url.try(:gsub, "postgres", "postgis")
           end
         end
       end
     end
   end
end
```

---

I works for me right now on Heroku free dyno with free postgres.

Comment: I spoke with the guys at Heroku and this solution is what they recommend. "PostGIS is available in public beta and you can try it with Hobby tier too. You can find the detail from PostGIS: Using Geospatial Data with Rails and Django Apps (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgis)." It works great :) - saving me 50 bucks a month

Answer (score 0):

I missed the fact that the Hobby tier databases don't support PostGIS.

Comment: They do support it now.